# Can i set multiple activities simultaniously in single screen?

Tags: android, android-activity

I just want to know how can we manage multiple screens using a single activity or not?

Comment: look at fragments or viewflipper ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- basically if you are talking about including another layout to your main layout will its possible just by using `<include>` in your layout that will add the other layout to your main layout. and you can as well declare `setContentView(R.layout.xxx)` in your code so when you click on another button your layout will be changed.
- if you are talking about two activities through .`Class` will i guess you can't do that but you can switch between them by using `Intent`.
- or you can use ViewPager orTabs to do that with the use of SharlockActionBar your app may support low api than 11.

Answer (score 1):

An Activity represents a single UI to one screen. You can switch between different layouts to represent that screen. Therefor Android gives multiply tools to achieve this, like VievFlipper which changes the whole layout at runtime.

Fragments are the key to make that screen modular. F.e. switch different areas of the screen for your need.

Because your question is very abstract it is hard to point to the right direction. But if you use the following tools you can build your UI like whatever you want:

[ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html)
[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)